# How do I screen for integers that are too big in my Rails model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, model, integer

I’m using Rails 4.2.7 with PostGres 9.5.  I have this column in my Rails migration ...

```
my_num               | integer                     |
```

In my model, I would like to screen for numbers that are too big and set them to nil.  For instance, the number “659722222222222” is getting set on my model and is causing the below error

```
Error during processing: (RangeError) 659722222222222 is out of range for ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQL::OID::Integer with limit 4
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/type/integer.rb:45:in `ensure_in_range'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/type/integer.rb:23:in `type_cast_for_database'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/quoting.rb:13:in `quote'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-import-0.16.1/lib/activerecord-import/import.rb:641:in `block (2 levels) in values_sql_for_columns_and_attributes'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-import-0.16.1/lib/activerecord-import/import.rb:631:in `each'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-import-0.16.1/lib/activerecord-import/import.rb:631:in `each_with_index'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-import-0.16.1/lib/activerecord-import/import.rb:631:in `each'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-import-0.16.1/lib/activerecord-import/import.rb:631:in `map'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-import-0.16.1/lib/activerecord-import/import.rb:631:in `block in values_sql_for_columns_and_attributes'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-import-0.16.1/lib/activerecord-import/import.rb:630:in `map'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-import-0.16.1/lib/activerecord-import/import.rb:630:in `values_sql_for_columns_and_attributes'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-import-0.16.1/lib/activerecord-import/import.rb:530:in `import_without_validations_or_callbacks'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-import-0.16.1/lib/activerecord-import/import.rb:490:in `import_with_validations'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-import-0.16.1/lib/activerecord-import/import.rb:417:in `import_helper'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-import-0.16.1/lib/activerecord-import/import.rb:331:in `import'
/Users/davea/Documents/workspace//app/services/abstract_import_service.rb:161:in `block in save_my_object__time_results'
```

Rather than save the model, I would like to set the field to nil only if it is set to an integer value that is too big for PostGres SQL.  How do I do this?

Note, I do NOT want to change teh column type of the PostGres column.  You didn't think this was going to be that easy, did you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`2147483647` is the max value of the type integer in Postgres.

```
before_save :is_too_big

def is_too_big
  if my_num > 2147483647
    # do something
  end
end
```

If you don't want put a *magic numbers to the code*, I suggest you catch an exeption when the out of range happens:

```
# somewhere in the code
u = User.new(my_num: 2147483648)
begin
 u.save
rescue RangeError => e
 u.my_num = nil
 u.save
end
```

Comment: Is there a constant that represents 2147483647 ?  I remember I lost points in a computer science class way back when for putting magic numbers in my code.

Comment: There's no constant for this. the `integer` type is that it is a 4-byte signed integer. from `-2147483648` to `+2147483647`.

Comment: @Dave you can derive that number, but it's still magically attached to knowing what Postgres' max is. In Ruby you can do `((2**32)/2)-1` to get this maximum (4 bytes is 32 bits, but half the numbers are negative).

Answer (score 0):

Add a before validation event

```
before_validation :ensure_my_num_ok
```

and just set the value if it's bad

```
def ensure_my_num_ok
  self.my_num = nil  if my_num > 100000000
end
```